# RegEx to get text within tags

Tags: regex, string

I need a [Regular Expressions](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/regextutorial.aspx) to get the text within 2 tags.

Lets say I want an array returned containing **any text within `<data`> and  `</data`> tags.**
Or any text **within "(" and ")" tags.**

How can I do that with RegEx's in C#?

---

An advanced question would be:

1. The input string is **"color=rgb(50,20,30)"**
2. How can I get the 3 numbers in 3 seperate array slots as returned by the RegEx processor in C#?

Comment: Similar to "Regex: To pull out a section a substing from a string between two tags" -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237/regex-to-pull-out-a-section-a-substing-from-a-string-between-two-tags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you specifically mentioned C#, here's how I'm doing that exact parsing:

```
private static readonly Regex RgbValuePattern = new Regex(@"(?<r>\d{1,3}) ?, ?(?<g>\d{1,3}) ?, ?(?<b>\d{1,3})",
                                                          RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);
```

Then later on...

```
var match = RgbValuePattern.Match(value);

if (match.Success)
{
    int r = Int32.Parse(match.Groups["r"].Value, NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
    int g = Int32.Parse(match.Groups["g"].Value, NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
    int b = Int32.Parse(match.Groups["b"].Value, NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
    return Color.FromArgb(r, g, b);
}
```

Comment: Gah!
This reminds me why I avoid regexps in C++ - extremely awkward to work with! Perl is still the best language for that...

Answer (score 4):

Perl regexp would be

```
$string =~ /color=rgb\((\d+),(\d+),(\d+)\)/;
@array = ($1,$2,$3);
```

But you probably need more information that this.

Answer (score 1):

This similar question has answers that will help:

- **[Regex: To pull out a section a substing from a string between two tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237/regex-to-pull-out-a-section-a-substing-from-a-string-between-two-tags)**

Answer (score 1):

Using Regex to parse XML is usually a really bad idea. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Answer (score 0):

I believe real problems will arise when you want to parse nesting constructs. For example, when you want to examine XML like this 
`<data><data>123</data><data>456</data></data>`
to extract data included in outermost `<data>` tags one RegEx alone would not be enough. Just warn you to not use RegEx where some more (powerful and specific) methods exist. Real XML parsers should be considered when doing more complex tasks on XML. My 2 cents...

Comment: Yeah, regexps are famous for not dealing with recursive data. Theoretically incapable of it, in fact.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. You can match finite recursion (e.g. 3 and no more nested tags) but can't solve problem for arbitrary level of recursion. Finite automaton just can't track infinite number of steps needed to get to any recursion level.

Comment: Recently found an interesting feature of .NET regex - balanced matching (see http://blogs.msdn.com/bclteam/archive/2005/03/15/396452.aspx ). So with such feature you actually *can* match brackets. Was a bit of surprise to me...