# How to match a string between keywords containing any symbol (including new lines) in regex

Tags: regex

I have this xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?mso-infoPathSolution solutionVersion="1.0.0.182" productVersion="15.0.0" PIVersion="1.0.0.0" href="http://sp01/hp/Therapy/Forms/template.xsn" name="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:infopath:Therapy:-myXSD-2013-03-01T10-07-30" ?>
<?mso-application progid="InfoPath.Document" versionProgid="InfoPath.Document.3"?>
<my:myFields
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:pc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2007/PartnerControls"
        xmlns:ma="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/metadata/properties/metaAttributes"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2009/WSSList/dataFields"
        xmlns:q="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2009/WSSList/queryFields"
        xmlns:dfs="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/dataFormSolution"
        xmlns:dms="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/documentManagement/types"
        xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:my="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2013-03-01T10:07:30"
        xmlns:xd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003"
        xml:lang="en-us">
    <my:PatientID>1</my:PatientID>
    <my:Name>name</my:Name>
    <my:Age>29.0000000000000</my:Age>
    <my:Gender>gender</my:Gender>
    <my:Date>2015-12-09</my:Date>
    <my:group1>
        <my:group2>
            <my:field1>1</my:field1>
            <my:PName>pname</my:PName>
            <my:PPrice>10000.0000000000</my:PPrice>
            <my:field11 xsi:nil="true"></my:field11>
        </my:group2>
        <my:group2>
            <my:field1>9</my:field1>
            <my:PName>pname
            </my:PName>
            <my:PPrice>10000.0000000000</my:PPrice>
            <my:field11 xsi:nil="true"></my:field11>
        </my:group2>
    </my:group1>
    <my:field4></my:field4>
    <my:field5></my:field5>
    <my:Status>false</my:Status>
    <my:Confirm>false</my:Confirm>
    <my:field6></my:field6>
    <my:field7></my:field7>
    <my:field8></my:field8>
    <my:TPrice>20000</my:TPrice>
    <my:field12></my:field12>
    <my:field13></my:field13>
    <my:insurance>1</my:insurance>
    <my:Partner>partner</my:Partner>
    <my:Doctor>doctor</my:Doctor>
</my:myFields>
```

And I want to filter this with regex and get only the value of tag , i.e.

```
<my:group1>
    <my:group2>
        <my:field1>1</my:field1>
        <my:PName>pname</my:PName>
        <my:PPrice>10000.0000000000</my:PPrice>
        <my:field11 xsi:nil="true"></my:field11>
    </my:group2>
    <my:group2>
        <my:field1>9</my:field1>
        <my:PName>pname
        </my:PName>
        <my:PPrice>10000.0000000000</my:PPrice>
        <my:field11 xsi:nil="true"></my:field11>
    </my:group2>
</my:group1>
```

I tried to filter it with this regex

```
<my:group1>(.*\r*\n*)*<\/my:group1>
```

but seems like i'm going by wrong direction. How do i filter ANY character between my keywords, including new lines?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8303488/regex-to-match-any-character-including-new-lines

Comment: @Ian I tried that, but didn't give the right result

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/cK7nT0/1)):

```
<my:group1>(.|\n|\r)*<\/my:group1>
```

But *please, please, please* use an xml parser to parse xml, not regex.

Comment: I just want to cut down all the other info and leave the group1 part,but your suggestion makes sense :)

Answer (score 1):

> How do i filter ANY character between my keywords, including new lines?

Since the `.` character doesn't include newline characters, you could use the `s` flag so that it matches all characters, including newlines - [**example**](https://regex101.com/r/kH8oZ3/1).

```
/<my:group1>(.*)<\/my:group1>/s
```

Alternatively, you could also use a character set to match all whitespace characters (`\s`) and all non-whitespace characters (`\S`), which will essentially match everything - [**example**](https://regex101.com/r/eC1xL3/1).

```
<my:group1>([\s\S]*)<\/my:group1>
```