# Regex: take string between <tag> and \n or </tag>

Tags: python, regex

I can't figure out where I'm wrong.

I have a pile of pages from where I need to get the content of the  tags and make it a file name.

My regex

```
title2 = re.search(r'(<title>)(.+)(</title>)', content)
filename_test = str(title2.group(2)+'.txt')
```

It works fine until it comes to a title like this:

```
<title>Klaatu - barada nikto
</title>
```

I've tried a lot of variants, none of them works.

Main idea is that something like this should have worked:

```
title2 = re.search(r'(<title>)(.+)(\n|(</title>))', content)
```

i.e. "stop when you come to new line **or** this tag"
But it doesn't.

Comment: And now you have two problems.

Comment: Don't parse HTML with regex..on a sidenote use `(?s)(<title>)(.+?)(</title>)`

Comment: If you want `.` in a regex to match `\n` then you need to use the `re.DOTALL` flag, which can be abbreviated as `re.S`.

Comment: Parse HTML with regex [at your own peril](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/4014959) :)

Comment: "But it doesn't." - yes it does.

Comment: Really?What I see as output is "string" then newline and then ".txt" instead of string.txt

Answer (score 0):

```
<(title)>[\S\s]*<\/title>
```

As you've found, `.` will not match newlines - you can use `[\S\s]` to match any character that "is not a space or is a space" - basically any character.

There are actually quite a few ways you can approach this - have a look at this question for alternatives: [Regex to match any character including new lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8303488/regex-to-match-any-character-including-new-lines)

Comment: Why use `[\S\s]` workaround when you have `re.S` flag (or inline `(?s)`) in Python?

Comment: It's not a duplicate. I do not need to include \n. Thought it's clear. I need everything after <title> and before \n or </title>