# Find Last Occurrence of Regex Word

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I find the last occurrence of a word with word boundaries? I created a regex expression of `/\btotal\b/` for the word. How would I use search() to find the last occurrence  of this expression? Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use negative lookahead to get the last match:

```
/(\btotal\b)(?!.*\b\1\b)/
```

[RegEx Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/lI0fF7/3)

[RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/lI0fF7/5)

`(?!.*\1)` is negative lookahead to assert that captured group #1 i.e. `total` word is NOT present ahead of the present match.

Comment: I tried the demo, but the match information section on website with your demo says: "No match groups were extracted.

This means that your pattern matches but there were no (capturing (groups)) in it that matched anything in the subject string." I was wondering what this meant? I ask because I tried your method, but I get -1 when I use it with the search function on a string that shows matches on regex101.com.

Comment: I also get two matches sometimes? How does that happen if this finds the last total?

Comment: [Check this demo](https://regex101.com/r/lI0fF7/5) Also keep in mind it can  potentially find `total` in **two different lines** not on same line.

Comment: Is it possible to find the last total of the two matches? By the way, thanks for the continued help!

Comment: Yes sure you can use [`/(\btotal\b)(?![^]*\b\1\b)/`](https://regex101.com/r/lI0fF7/7)

Comment: Sorry, one more question anubhava. Could regex also include numbers and underscore as a word boundary so 'total' could be found in the following example? https://regex101.com/r/lI0fF7/8

Comment: @anubhava Is there any way to extract the last currency value?  I have the expression ([+-]?\$[0-9]{1,3}(?:,?[0-9]{3})*\.[0-9]{2}) to match all currency values, but only need the last one.  If necessary, I will do programmatically but wanted to see if there was a regex I could use.  [Regex Sample](https://regex101.com/r/4ZyN2e/1)  Should I open a new question?

Comment: @WilliamHumphries: I suggest using `.*(([+-]?\$[0-9]{1,3}(?:,?[0-9]{3})*\.[0-9]{2}))` and use first capture group. You can check demo here: https://regex101.com/r/4ZyN2e/2

Comment: @anubhava I'm facing issue with capturing the first group, I added what I thought was a non-capturing group (?:.*) before the expression but still returning a whole sentence.  Also tried \1 suggested from [Regex Buddy](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html)  but couldn't get a full match of the value $60,000.  [Regex101 Sample](https://regex101.com/r/4ZyN2e/3)

Comment: Just use `.*([+-]?\$[0-9]{1,3}(?:,?[0-9]{3})*\.[0-9]{2})` and use 1st capture group

Answer (score 14):

Without using the lookaheads but using the same regex (having applied the `g`, i.e. global, flag), the option would be to match the string with regex and get the last match.

```
var matches = yourString.match(/\btotal\b/g);
var lastMatch = matches[matches.length-1];
```

Comment: `lastMatch` is a string, `total`, he already knows that.

Comment: @run_the_race so? the `lastMatch` can give you way more information than that like e.g. the index for instance or if using match groups those as ell etc

Comment: @derHugo, I think he is trying to find the index or position of where total is in the string? If that is what he is trying to achieve, getting the string `total` does not help him as he knows what the pattern is. As mentioned `lastMatch` is a `string`, not sure how this `string` is supposed to yield the index and "way more information"? Maybe you think its supposed to be a match object. But try the code for yourself.

Comment: @run_the_race yep sorry, my bad. Coming from c# I hoped that to carry more information than just the string

Answer (score 0):

I like @anubhava's answer. And in case your string might contain line breaks, you can try the following Negative Lookahead:

```
(\btotal\b)(?!.*[\r\n]*.*\1)
```

See [an example](https://regex101.com/r/NQFqhR/1) on regex101. Also see below, we replace the last occurrence of `total` with `<TOTAL>`

```
var str = `
something total abc 
total 


foo total anything here
total



Anything total done!
`;

var finalStr = str.replace(/(\btotal\b)(?!.*[\r\n]*.*\1)/, "<TOTAL>");

console.log(finalStr)
```

And you will get:

```
something total abc 
total 


foo total anything here
total



Anything <TOTAL> done!
```

Answer (score 0):

@anubhava answer is correct for single line inputs, but the idea is correct thank you for sharing it!

I think his answer can be improved (but please do correct me if I'm wrong) with version below:

```regex
/\b(total)\b(?![\s\S]*\b\1\b)/
```

The difference here is that `[\s\S]*` will effectively [match *any* character](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8303552/1262357), new lines included. Also word boundary `\b` are not really needed in the capturing group.

In the linked 2nd example by @anubhava it's matching only the very first `total` word found because the pattern `(?!.*\b\1\b)` will not consider newlines. You can verify by adding the word `total` somewhere at the beginning of the sample mail text.

Demo link:
https://regex101.com/r/VlhRWM/3

I'm just a bit worried about performance of the `[\S\s]*` pattern.

Also I think that the reported errors in comments, for not found matching group, are related to the regex ECMAScript flavor selected in the linked demo, using PCRE is reporting correctly the match.

---

**NB.**
This pattern will consider a valid match in the ENTIRE input provided. If you need a *per line* match, you need to enable the `/g` global flag and use @anubhava answer!