# How to match the last occurrence of a pattern using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like

```
{{token1}}/{{token2}}
```

I want to match `{{token2}}` using regex.

other possible cases that it should match are

`{{token1}}/{` should match `{` (the last one).

`{{token1}}/{{` should match `{{` (the last one).

`{{token1}}/{{token2` should match `{{token2`.

I tried `/\S+$/` but it works when the string is `{{token1}} {{token2}}`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "match"?. Do you want to "extract it"?

Comment: @Tushar I have update the question with all possible scenarios

Comment: @TheLostMind I am searching this pattern in a string.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find Last Occurrence of Regex Word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38490160/find-last-occurrence-of-regex-word)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a negative lookahead regex:

```
/{+[^}]*}*(?!.*{)/
```

`(?!.*{)` is negative lookahead that asserts we don't have any `{` ahead of the current position.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/UzZAMo/4)