# Extract last 4 consecutive digits in a string

Tags: php, regex

I want to match/extract the last 4 consecutive digits in a string. The pattern I need to match is therefore `[0-9]{4}`, but only the last instance of it in the string - if there are any non-numbers in between, it should match the next instance instead.

Some examples:

```
ABC123456789A9876  // should extract 9876
ABCD1234567890F23  // should extract 7890
1234ABCD567JIJLMN  // should extract 1234
ABCDEFG1234-!.567  // should extract 1234
```

How can I accomplish this using regex? Alternatively if there's an easier way to do this programmatically with PHP/Laravel I'd also be open to it.

Comment: What have you tried to achieve this?

Comment: @matiaslauriti A lot in the last few hours, but since nothing came close to working I don't see the reason in polluting the question with irrelevant attempts. See also: [every](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10294626/regex-to-check-for-4-consecutive-digits) other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41870124/regex-to-find-last-occurrence-of-pattern-in-a-string) about [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40926332/how-to-match-the-last-occurrence-of-a-pattern-using-regex).

Comment: [This question is being discussed on meta.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426031/why-was-my-regex-question-downvoted-and-closed-when-its-as-good-or-better-than)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two ways to do that.

**Use \K**

Match

```
.*\K\d{4}
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cDTIG3/1)

The component parts of the expression are as follows.

```
.*     # match zero or more characters other than line
       # terminators, as many as possible
\K     # reset the start of the match and discard all
       # previously-consumed characters
\d{4}  # match 4 digits
```

**Use a capture group**

Match

```
.*(\d{4})
```

and extract the four digits from capture group 1.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tJjsNB/1)

The expression reads, "Match zero or more characters other than line terminators, as many as possible, then then match four digits and save the four digits in capture group 1".

Comment: If the first example works it'll be very clever. Will test and report back.

Comment: Nice use of `\K` to get rid of the capture group. The second solution is probably not worth keeping, the negative lookahead for `.*\d{4}` really blows out the steps when you get a really long string with more than one 4 digit sequence