# Is there a regex to remove the last multiple occurrences of a pattern in a sentence

Tags: regex

I want to remove multiple hashtags from the end of a paragraph.

```
#abc #def This is a test paragraph. #ads I only want to remove the hashtags after the full stop at the end and keep the hashtag at the center. These hashtags should be removed. #ads #ime #abc
```

I tried this regular expression **/. #([^\]*)/g**
But it is removing everything from the full stop of the first sentence because the full stop is followed by **#ads**. How should I remove the hashtags **at the end of the paragraph**?

I'm using a no-code platform to work. So there are limitations for me to write code. But I'm using the **replaceRegex** function for doing this.

**What I have**

```
var.a = "#abc #def This is a test paragraph. #ads I only want to remove the hashtags after the full stop at the end and keep the hashtag at the center. These hashtags should be removed. #ads #ime #abc"
```

**Function**

```
{{replaceRegex var.a '/\. #([^\\]*)/g' " "}}
```

**Actual Result**

```
#abc #def This is a test paragraph
```

**Expected Result**

```
#abc #def This is a test paragraph. #ads I only want to remove the hashtags after the full stop at the end and keep the hashtag at the center. These hashtags should be removed.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find Last Occurrence of Regex Word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38490160/find-last-occurrence-of-regex-word)

Comment: regex language is different depending on the programming language used. Please specify your coding language in the tags of your question.

Comment: @LaytonGB The platform I use works on javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an alternative way to do the job: Rather than finding the end of the string, it finds the text-groups starting with `#` that do not have any other character groups after them.

```
(?<=\.\s+)(#[a-zA-Z]+ *)+(?! *[^\s])
```

You can see the results here: https://regex101.com/r/1JpJPT/1

Comment: It worked. Is there any way to remove the first hashtags from the sentence?

Comment: Your question specifically shows you want to keep those hashtags. If you want the answer to a new question, you should mark an answer as the solution to this question and then ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/SGHTI9/1/) might work:

```
\. #[^\\.]*$
//      ^  ^
```

It adds a `.` to your exclusion list and an end enchor `$` at the end

Using your script:

```
{{replaceRegex var.a '/\. #[^\\.]*$/g' "."}}
```

Comment: It worked. Is there any way to remove the first hashtags from the sentence?