# Substitute last occurrence of a word Regex Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to substitute the last occurrence of a text with nothing:

```
let text ="eb8583fb8d0c8aadce-lad7ff779e5e53ee-la.gif"; 
text = text.replace('/(\b-la\b)(?!.*\1)/',"");
```

taking the above code as an example I want text to be:
eb8583fb8d0c8aadced7ff779e5e53ee-la.gif
according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38490160/find-last-occurrence-of-regex-word) this should work, but actually not, why?

Comment: `text = text.replace(/(\b-la\b)(?!.*\b\1\b)/,"");`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew works!!! really really thanks!

Comment: Why reopen vote? To fix a typo?